# Best way to find 2 specific points on this image?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, image-processing

I am trying to do a specific task in javascript. Given the below image:

[image]

I am trying to find two specific points given by the red points

[image]

The actual image has white (not transparent) spacing padding all around it. 
Also the gray circle may not be in the center, it could actually be anywhere in the main image.

Given these data, I am looking for an algorithm that can locate the two red points, i.e. find the x,y coordinates of it.

My best way so far, is to start from the center, and do a BFS algorithm to find the first gray pixel. Then do another BFS traveling on only the gray/black pixels until I find the darkest pixel, which would be the right side red point. Then do another BFS from there traveling on only the black/gray pixels but storing any white adjacent pixels, but only keep track of the one that increases its distance to the blackest pixel. This would get the left side red point.

Does anyone know of a faster algorithm to get them?

Comment: Will the white and black regions always fall on opposite sides of a horizontal chord dissecting the centre of the circle?

Comment: Yes they are always opposite from each other.

Comment: And always across the middle of the circle, on a horizontal line? I.e, if you find the lightest or darkest pixel, can you then just search along the x axis, keeping the y coordinates the same?

Comment: And can you post your code so far.

Comment: Actually, the circle can be rotated as well, by any amount, skewed too.

Comment: As I understand it, you're searching pixel by pixel. However, the lighter and darker regions are quite big, so you could easily jump around on a grid in steps of 10 or 20 pixels, until you find a slightly darker or lighter pixel, and then move in (gradually) smaller steps.

Answer (score 0):

1. **select all non background pixels neighboring background pixel**

   so create a list of points which are not fully white and have at least one fully white pixel neighbor. This task should be `O(xs,ys)` where `xs,ys` is the resolution of your image. You can do this with simple 2 nested `for` loops and 2 if statements ... This will give you the circumference points of the disc.
2. **Now process all these points and select darkest from them.**

   Simple `O(n)` `for` loop with `if` statements for finding `min` the result is your darkest point. Brightest point can not be searched in this way due to anti-aliasing interference with background color.
3. **Find center**

   simply compute average position of all selected points.
4. **mirror darkest point around center**

   that will give you brightest point position.

**Here simple C++ example:**

```cpp
picture pic0,pic1;
    // pic0 - source img
    // pic1 - output img
//                    0xAARRGGBB
const DWORD col_back=0x00FFFFFF;    // white
const DWORD col_mid =0x00888888;    // gray inside
const DWORD int_mid =3*0x88;        // intensity of gray inside
int i,x,y;
_pnt p,*pp,p0,p1;
List<_pnt> pnt;
color c;

// copy source image to output and ignore alpha channel
pic1=pic0&0x00FFFFFF;

// circumference points
for (y=1;y<pic1.ys-1;y++)
 for (x=1;x<pic1.xs-1;x++)
  if (pic1.p[y][x].dd!=col_back)
   if ((pic1.p[y-1][x].dd==col_back)
     ||(pic1.p[y+1][x].dd==col_back)
     ||(pic1.p[y][x-1].dd==col_back)
     ||(pic1.p[y][x+1].dd==col_back))
    {
    p.x=x; p.y=y;       // position
    c=pic1.p[y][x];     // intensity
    p.i=DWORD(c.db[picture::_r])
       +DWORD(c.db[picture::_g])
       +DWORD(c.db[picture::_b]);
    pnt.add(p);         // add to list
    pic1.p[y][x].dd=0x000000FF; // blue dot for selected pixel
    }
// p0 = darkest point
// p1 = avg point (center)
p0=pnt[0];
p1.x=0; p1.y=0; p1.i=0;
for (pp=pnt.dat,i=0;i<pnt.num;i++,pp++)
    {
    if (p0.i>pp->i) p0=*pp;
    p1.x+=pp->x; p1.y+=pp->y; p1.i++;
    }
if (p1.i) { p1.x/=p1.i; p1.y/=p1.i; }
// p1 = mirror of p0
p1.x+=p1.x-p0.x;
p1.y+=p1.y-p0.y;

// render found points
i=5;
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=clBlack;
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clRed;
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(p0.x-i,p0.y-i,p0.x+i,p0.y+i);
pic1.bmp->Canvas->Ellipse(p1.x-i,p1.y-i,p1.x+i,p1.y+i);
```

**I use my own picture class for images so some members are:**

`xs,ys` is size of image in pixels

`p[y][x].dd` is pixel at `(x,y)` position as 32 bit integer type

`clear(color)` clears entire image with `color`

`resize(xs,ys)` resizes image to new resolution

`bmp` is **VCL** encapsulated **GDI** Bitmap with `Canvas` access

`pf` holds actual pixel format of the image:

```
enum _pixel_format_enum
    {
    _pf_none=0, // undefined
    _pf_rgba,   // 32 bit RGBA
    _pf_s,      // 32 bit signed int
    _pf_u,      // 32 bit unsigned int
    _pf_ss,     // 2x16 bit signed int
    _pf_uu,     // 2x16 bit unsigned int
    _pixel_format_enum_end
    };
```

`color` and pixels are encoded like this:

```
union color
    {
    DWORD dd; WORD dw[2]; byte db[4];
    int i; short int ii[2];
    color(){}; color(color& a){ *this=a; }; ~color(){}; color* operator = (const color *a) { dd=a->dd; return this; }; /*color* operator = (const color &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/
    };
```

The bands are:

```
enum{
    _x=0,   // dw
    _y=1,

    _b=0,   // db
    _g=1,
    _r=2,
    _a=3,

    _v=0,   // db
    _s=1,
    _h=2,
    };
```

I also use mine dynamic list template so:

`List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`

`xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list

`xxx[7]` access array element (safe)

`xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)

`xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array

`xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`

`xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

**And finaly the result preview:**

[image: preview]

blue points are the selected circumference points and red dots are the found points.